# How to display list data from script to template in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have the function of display data from major table on MySQL. I want to display the type of that list of major by comparing with the id of the faculty table like below. I have it displayed on console.log, how do I display it on the template? Thanks

**Template tag**

```
<td>
{{ inputText }}
</td>
```

**Script tag**

```
data() {
return {
    majors:[],
    faculties:[],
    form: new Form({
        major_id:'',
        major_code:'',
        major_name:'',
        major_faculty:'',
        major_status: '',
    }),
    inputText: '',
  };
},
computed: {
 filterFaculty() {
    for(let i in this.majors) {
        this.faculties.forEach((element) => {
            if(element.faculty_code==this.majors[i].major_faculty) {
                this.inputText=element.faculty_name;
            }else {
                return '-';
            }
        });
     }
  }
},
mounted() {
  this.fetchFaculties();
  this.fetchMajors();
},
methods: {
  fetchFaculties(page_url) {
    let vm = this;
    page_url = '../../api/admin/edu-faculty/faculty/faculty';
    fetch(page_url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
        this.faculties = res.data;
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
},
fetchMajors(page_url) {
    let vm = this;
    page_url = '../../api/admin/edu-major/major/'+this.currentEntries+'?page='+this.pagination.current_page;
    fetch(page_url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
        this.majors = res.data;
        this.pagination = res.meta;
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
  },
 }
```

Comment: Is your template only the td tag? What did you to for debugging? Would the [Vue Development Tools extension](https://devtools.vuejs.org/) help? You can see variable values directly with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've found solution for problem

**Script tag**

```
methods: {
   filterFaculty(major) {
      const faculty = this.faculties.find((fac) => fac.faculty_code === major.major_faculty);
        return faculty.faculty_name;
    },
}
```

**Template tag**

```
<td>
   {{ filterFaculty(major) }}
 </td>
```